# Removing variable number from string

Tags: python

I have several strings in a list:

`['~/tmp/GROUP-G07T01/items/GROUP-G07T01-000021_item2.png', '~/tmp/GROUP-G07T01/items/GROUP-G07T01-000021_item3.png', '~/tmp/GROUP-G07T01/items/GROUP-G07T01-000021_item4.png'`

I need to remove the `'item2', 'item3', 'item4'` so I can later replace with another variable that changes each time that I am passing in: `variable = {changing item}`

I have tried things like `string.replace("item{i}.format(i) for i in range(20), "")` or `re.sub` but I can't seem to get it to work - any suggestions?

I would expect the output `[~/tmp/GROUP-G07T01/items/GROUP-G07T01-000021_{changing item1}.png`, ~/tmp/GROUP-G07T01/items/GROUP-G07T01-000021_{changing item2}.png`, ~/tmp/GROUP-G07T01/items/GROUP-G07T01-000021_{changing item3}.png`]

Comment: Add list of strings and expected output to your question.

Comment: I have added more strings to the example, and an expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` to replace string (`'item<number>'`) like so:

```
re.sub(r'item\d+', var, x)
```

**Code**:

```
import re

lst = ['~/tmp/GROUP-G07T01/items/GROUP-G07T01-000021_item2.png', 'some/thing/0034_item5.png']
var = 'foo'

result = [re.sub(r'item\d+', var, x) for x in lst]
# ['~/tmp/GROUP-G07T01/items/GROUP-G07T01-000021_foo.png', 'some/thing/0034_foo.png']
```

Comment: Thank you, must have done my original re.sub attempt incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `re` regex module. You need to use a valid regex. You can specify one or more characters 0 to 9 by using `[0-9]+`.

```py
fixed_str = re.replace("item[0-9]+", "", input_str)
```

Here is the reference to how to format regexs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

You can also use online sites such as regex101.com to experiment with regex formatting in real time to make sure it works ahead of time.